# How to resolve this diferential equation $y^2 y^{\prime}=x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I see it is non-linear, but not sure if that is important here.

I got the solution for the homogeneous in this way:

$$y^2 y^\prime=0 \rightarrow y^\prime=0 \rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=0\rightarrow \int dy=\int 0\rightarrow y+ k_1 = k_2\rightarrow y=c\text{ where }c\in \mathbb{R}$$

I dont know if this is ok, and how to continue. I ask for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not separate it?
$$y^2 \frac{dy}{dx} = x^3$$
is equivalent to
$$y^2dy = x^3 dx$$
and now both sides integrate out?

Answer (score 2):

$$y^2\frac{dy}{dx}=x^3\implies \int y^2dy=\int x^3dx\implies \frac13y^3=\frac14x^4+C\;\ldots$$